# How to find number of nodes connected to two nodes in a graph?

Tags: r, matrix, graph, igraph

I have a direct graph with the following adjacency matrix

```
as.matrix(read.table(header=T, text=
" A B C D E F
A 0 1 0 0 0 1
B 0 0 0 0 0 1
C 0 1 0 0 1 0
D 0 1 0 0 1 1
E 0 0 0 0 0 1
F 0 0 0 0 0 0"))
```

I want to do some matrix manipulation that can give me the number of unique nodes that follow two nodes. For example in the previous matrix the result should be

```
  A B C D E F
A|0 3 0 0 2 4|
B|3 3 3 3 3 5|
C|0 3 0 0 2 4|
D|0 3 0 0 2 4|
E|2 3 2 2 2 5|
F|4 5 4 4 5 4|
```

I'm using R for my coding. That would be great if somebody can help on that

Comment: What do you mean by *"the number of unique nodes that follow two nodes"*. ie. can you explain a bit how you got your output. thanks

Comment: @user20650 - You might as well just wrap it with `dput()` at that point. ;-)

Comment: yes  suppose @HaddE.Nuff ... but like this can still eyeball it , and i was going to add some igraph code as well to complete their example --- then thought id leave it for the op

Comment: This is a twitter network data, I want to find that how many unique followers are following two selected users.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, I share it as it might be useful:

```
D<-colSums(A)
B<-matrix(D,ncol=length(D),nrow=length(D))
Result<-B+t(B)-t(A)%*%A
```